# instale pip para instalar aws cli, pero al reiniciar sesion remota por ssh se elimina, no me aparece nada

Tags: aws, ssh, pip

El problema que tengo es que, para instalar aws cli tengo que instalar pip y todo funciona bien cuando lo instalo la primera vez funciona bien, estoy conectado por ssh a mi servidor y cuando vuelvo abrir la sesión  no se encuentra el pip, utilizo el comando pip --versión o simplemente pip y me sale que el comando no fue encontrado. ¿Es normal por la sesion remota?

Comment: Si utilizaste el comando `EXPORT` desde linea de comandos deja de ser válido cuando termina tu sesión, tienes que ejecutarlo nuevamente o incluirlo en tu `.bash_profile`. ¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas?

Comment: El sistema que utilizo es Debian Jessie

Comment: Y que comando `EXPORT` utilizaste la primera vez para que funcione?

Comment: el siguiente: export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

Comment: Intenta con este comando `echo -e 'export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` para que persista y no te olvides de reiniciar la sesión.

Comment: Gracias lo intentare y pongo resultados pero como reinicio la sesion , normal o hay algun comando para eso, realmente soy muy nueva para esto, espero entiendas.Gracias

Comment: Tienes que salir con exit e inicias la sesión ssh como normalmente lo haces ;)

Comment: Si funciono, en verdad gracias n.n

Comment: De nada :) No te olvides pasar por el [tour] para saber mas del funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla!